# Obtener mas de 1 valor máximo de una columna MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, maxima

estoy trabajando con una consulta que me devuelva los empleados que mas vendieron a lo largo del año. El problema es cuando dos empleados tienen la misma cantidad vendida (Monto_Logrado), solo me trae un empleado con la función MAX()

```
   SELECT idEmpleado, Empleado.nombre, SUM(montoLogrado) as Monto_Logrado, SUM(montoMes) as Meta_Anual FROM MetaDetalle
INNER JOIN Empleado ON MetaDetalle.idEmpleado = Empleado.id
INNER JOIN Meta ON Meta.id = MetaDetalle.idMeta
GROUP BY Empleado.id;
```

```
+------------+--------+---------------+------------+
| idEmpleado | nombre | Monto_Logrado | Meta_Anual |
+------------+--------+---------------+------------+
|          1 | Juan   |      88750.00 |    7500.00 |
|          2 | Rocio  |       9400.00 |    7500.00 |
|          4 | Pedro  |       9500.00 |    7500.00 |
|          7 | Carlos |      88750.00 |    7500.00 |
+------------+--------+---------------+------------+
```

Con MAX() me devuelve solo el primer empleado a pesar de que son dos.

```
SELECT Tabla.idEmpleado, Tabla.nombre, MAX(Tabla.Monto_Logrado) AS Monto_Logrado FROM(
SELECT idEmpleado, Empleado.nombre, SUM(montoLogrado) as Monto_Logrado, SUM(montoMes) as Meta_Anual FROM MetaDetalle
INNER JOIN Empleado ON MetaDetalle.idEmpleado = Empleado.id
INNER JOIN Meta ON Meta.id = MetaDetalle.idMeta
GROUP BY Empleado.id
) as Tabla;
```

```
+------------+--------+---------------+
| idEmpleado | nombre | Monto_Logrado |
+------------+--------+---------------+
|          1 | Juan   |      88750.00 |
+------------+--------+---------------+
```

Comment: Agrupa por el nombre del empleado también

Comment: Ya lo agrupe por idEmpleado pero me devuelve todos los empleados, no solo los mas altos

Comment: Cuando agrupes haz un order by por el monto logrado de forma desc y un limit 2 a ver si asi sale

Comment: Has probado a hacer un SELECT normal y en el WHERE hace un subSelect con el que pides el maximo comparado el columna

Comment: Usar limit 2 solo te traerá 2 datos MAX(), pero asumiendo antes de la consulta que son solo 2, de igual manera podrían ser 3 ó 4 ,y si todos los valores MAX() son iguales, cual valor debería devolver ?, creo que hay algo que definir antes de hacer la consulta creo que lo mas idóneo sería establecer un valor sobre el cual devolver la consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es tu primer *query* sin la tabla `Meta` que no usas en el ejemplo:

```
SELECT   d.idEmpleado, e.nombre, SUM( d.montoLogrado ) AS Monto_Logrado
FROM     MetaDetalle d
JOIN     Empleado e ON e.id = d.idEmpleado
GROUP BY d.idEmpleado;
```

El resultado que ya conocemos:

```
+------------+--------+---------------+
| idEmpleado | nombre | Monto_Logrado |
+------------+--------+---------------+
|          1 | Juan   |         88750 |
|          2 | Rocio  |          9400 |
|          4 | Pedro  |          9500 |
|          7 | Carlos |         88750 |
+------------+--------+---------------+
```

De este resultado queremos seleccionar todas las filas cuyo `Monto_Logrado` sea el máximo. No podemos buscarlas con un `WHERE` porque se aplicaría antes del `GROUP BY`. Para aplicar una condición después del `GROUP BY` usamos [`HAVING`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#idm45946581547024):

```
SELECT   d.idEmpleado, e.nombre, SUM( d.montoLogrado ) AS Monto_Logrado
FROM     MetaDetalle d
JOIN     Empleado e ON e.id = d.idEmpleado
GROUP BY d.idEmpleado
HAVING   Monto_Logrado = (
    SELECT   SUM( d2.montoLogrado ) AS s
    FROM     MetaDetalle d2
    GROUP BY d2.idEmpleado
    ORDER BY s DESC
    LIMIT    1
)
```

lo cual nos da el resultado que estábamos buscando:

```
+------------+--------+---------------+
| idEmpleado | nombre | Monto_Logrado |
+------------+--------+---------------+
|          1 | Juan   |         88750 |
|          7 | Carlos |         88750 |
+------------+--------+---------------+
```

No sé si se puede hacer sin usar *subqueries* o sin usar `HAVING`, supongo que sí.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Si era así como pusiste aquí! Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Con esta consulta deberías obtener lo que esperas.

He usado alias cortos para las tablas, de modo que la consulta no quede tan farragosa. No me queda claro a qué tabla pertenecen las columnas `montoLogrado` y `montoMes`, he supuesto que a `MetaDetalle` si no es así, pon a esas columnas el alias de la tabla que les corresponda.

```
SELECT 
    em.idEmpleado, 
    em.nombre, 
    SUM(md.montoLogrado) as Monto_Logrado, 
    SUM(md.montoMes) as Meta_Anual 
FROM MetaDetalle md
    INNER JOIN Empleado em ON md.idEmpleado = em.Empleado.id
    INNER JOIN Meta me ON me.id = md.idMeta
    GROUP BY md.idEmpleado
    ORDER BY Monto_Logrado,em.nombre DESC;
```

Siendo que se agrupa por `md.idEmpleado`, deberá diferenciarte los empleados, aunque tengan en `Monto_Logrado` el mismo valor. Si te interesa únicamente `N` cantidad de registros, una especie de `TOP N`, entonces le agregas `LIMIT N`  al final, donde `N` sería el total de filas que quieres obtener.

Comment: Como norma, ese group by solo anda en mysql viejo.. en el nuevo, todos los campos que no forman parte de una funcion de agrupacion deben estar en el group by